# Should legal questions be allowed on this stack?

Tags: discussion

Do we want to allow [this sort](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/if-i-was-to-open-a-us-based-xmr-exchange-what-laws-i-need-to-consider) of question on Monero SE?

As an alternative would it be better to refer users to https://law.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Answer (score 1):

I find the legal aspect to be too complex and critical to be answered by non specialists.

As illustrated by the lack of upvote to the answer of the cited question, I don't think that this community has that kind of skills. There is clearly not enough members with legal skills to have multiple answers and aware votes.

So, fwiw, i am in favor of moving legal questions to law.stackexchange.com.